# How to add error code numbers to the output text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script which loops through all windows errors and puts them in a text file called `helplog2.txt`. However, they are not separated by blank lines and the error messages do not have the error numbers before them.

Is there any way to fix that?

Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off
If Exist HelpLog2.txt Del HelpLog2.txt
(for /l %%i in (0,1,99999) do net helpmsg %%i 1>NUL 2>&1 && echo %%i & net helpmsg %%i | findstr /i "[a-z]" >> HelpLog2.txt)
Start "" HelpLog2.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this batch code:

```
@echo off
del HelpLog2.txt 2>nul
for /L %%I in (0,1,9) do for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe helpmsg %%I 2^>^&1') do >>HelpLog2.txt echo     %%I: %%J
for /L %%I in (10,1,99) do for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe helpmsg %%I 2^>^&1 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /C:"NET HELPMSG 3871"') do >>HelpLog2.txt echo    %%I: %%J
for /L %%I in (100,1,999) do for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe helpmsg %%I 2^>^&1 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /C:"NET HELPMSG 3871"') do >>HelpLog2.txt echo   %%I: %%J
for /L %%I in (1000,1,9999) do for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe helpmsg %%I 2^>^&1 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /C:"NET HELPMSG 3871"') do >>HelpLog2.txt echo  %%I: %%J
for /L %%I in (10000,1,99999) do for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe helpmsg %%I 2^>^&1 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /C:"NET HELPMSG 3871"') do >>HelpLog2.txt echo %%I: %%J
start "" HelpLog2.txt
```

It takes several minutes to finish, but finally you should have the wanted information in well formatted file `HelpLog2.txt`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `net /?`
- `net helpmsg /?`